# using a datatable or just load data infile?

Tags: c#, mysql, datatable

i have a csv file which data is in this type...(date,time,id)

```
20120131, 07:17:40, BK01
20120131, 07:17:41, BK02
20120121, 07:50:04, BK05
```

then..i want to store this data into a table..
i read about LOAD DATA INFILE but...
as far as i know(not much), LDI 
is for when the data column in my csv is totally same with my db table..

but in my db table there is another column..
which is Status..

```
20120131, 07:17:40, BK01, STATUSHERE
20120131, 07:17:41, BK02, ??
20120121, 07:50:04, BK05, ??
```

this Status based on the time in csv file...
i mean here..how can i set the status and then store it
with the data from csv file altogether into?
or is it by using data table/dataset?

thank you in advance..

Comment: not sure if you already checked my answer. Did you play around with LOAD DATA INFILE?

Answer (score 0):

LOAD DATA INFILE does not require the columns in CSV to match the columns in your table. You can specify column names in your LOAD DATA INFILE query in which you would like to insert values. Here is a text snippet from [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html)

> The following example loads all columns of the persondata table:
>
> LOAD DATA INFILE 'persondata.txt' INTO TABLE persondata;
>
> By default, when no column list is provided at the end of the LOAD DATA INFILE
>   statement, input lines are expected to contain a field for each table
>   column. If you want to load only some of a table's columns, specify a
>   column list:
>
> LOAD DATA INFILE 'persondata.txt' INTO TABLE persondata
>   (col1,col2,...);
>
> You must also specify a column list if the order of
>   the fields in the input file differs from the order of the columns in
>   the table. Otherwise, MySQL cannot tell how to match input fields with
>   table columns.

However, I'm not sure I fully understand your need -

**NEED 1:** would you like to insert only the 3 columns in your CSV file to your table ignoring what goes into the Status column? If yes, the above can help.

**NEED 2:** would you like to insert values into Status column? In that case, simply add a fourth column to your CSV file and then run LOAD DATA INFILE.

**NEED 3:** would you like to calculate the values for Status column at run-time? Use SET syntax in this case. The below text snippet might help:

> The column list can contain either column names or user variables.
>   With user variables, the SET clause enables you to perform
>   transformations on their values before assigning the result to
>   columns.
>
> User variables in the SET clause can be used in several ways. The
>   following example uses the first input column directly for the value
>   of t1.column1, and assigns the second input column to a user variable
>   that is subjected to a division operation before being used for the
>   value of t1.column2:
>
> LOAD DATA INFILE 'file.txt'   INTO TABLE t1   (column1, @var1)   SET
>   column2 = @var1/100;
>
> The SET clause can be used to supply values not derived from the input file. The following statement sets column3 to the current date and time:
>
> LOAD DATA INFILE 'file.txt'   INTO TABLE t1   (column1, column2)   SET
>   column3 = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
>
> You can also discard an input value by
>   assigning it to a user variable and not assigning the variable to a
>   table column:
>
> LOAD DATA INFILE 'file.txt'   INTO TABLE t1   (column1, @dummy,
>   column2, @dummy, column3);

Hope it helps! You may read more on the documentation page.